# how can I create designed properties

Tags: c#, winforms

how can I create designed properties  in user control like  DataBindings property of TextBox control

Can someone help me with a link or video tutorial

Comment: Are you looking for `UITypeEditor` and `EditorAttribute`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19191fh.aspx wich will help you in creating designtime properties. Look especially at DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute.